# How to hash a 32bit int to 10bit int?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, hash, unsigned-integer

How to hash a 32bit unsigned int(0~4294967295) to 10bit unsigned int(0~1023)?
least collisions and fast are important.Please write samples in C/C++ if convenient.

Sorry, I didn't ask in a good way, this is not my homework. Maybe the question background would be helpful. I'm writing a server, this server must handle < 1024 connections from every single client. every client has its independent IP address, stored as 32bit unsigned int.That's how the question goes from.

Comment: You certainly will have collisions. Also, *we will not write your code for you*. Please show us your own efforts, and we will gladly help you with specific problems.

Comment: StackOverflow is a place to ask questions when you get stuck, not a place to ask others to do your homework for you. Feel free to come back and ask for help if your code doesn't always work, or if you think it takes too long, or you can't figure out how to reduce the collision rate, etc.

Comment: I don't think that you will be able to avoid collisions here

Comment: Without writing code, one can shed some light and be helpful :p

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y @sarnold .Sorry, I didn't ask in a good way, this is not my homework. Maybe the question background would be helpful.

Comment: I'm writing a server, this server must handle < 1024 connections from every single client. every client has its independent IP address, stored as 32bit unsigned int.That's how the question goes from.

Answer (score 2):

Under certain conditions (like having to hash at most 2^10 known items), you can have no collisions. For more speed, tolerating a bit of collision might help. More about that here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function

GNU Perfect Hash Function Generator http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/

A cheap, low-size key hashing is Pearson Hashing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_hashing

Comment: As your condition, I'm having to hash < 2^10 known items.Thanks for your help.